# Adding or removing method that is sequentially last renders C program useless

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have a simple software for printing e circuit board in the console. I run the program below with the addBoard() (poorly named method for adding component) and it just runs printing nothing. Even though it is last in the sequence. If I comment it out the program works fine and prints everything out in the Visual Studio Code terminal window.

What could this be due to? (also any pointers on my usage of pointers hehe... or anything else that isn't best practice is hugely appreciated.) Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *posArr[10][30];

void printInstructions(){
    printf("Hello and welcome! Here you can configure your own breadboard\n");
    printf("To do this you will use coordinates using this syntax:\n");
    printf("width: 3\n");
    printf("height: 5\n");
    printf("After that a component will be choosen.\n");
    printf("It would look like below:\n");    
}

void printBoard(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) //Height
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 1; j <= 30; j++) //Width
        {
            printf("%s", posArr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void clearBoard(){
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) //Height
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= 30; j++) //Width
        {
            posArr[i][j] = ". ";
        }
    }
}

void buildBoard(int *width, int *height){
    //*height -= 1;
    //*width -= 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) //Height
    {
        //printf("\n");
        for (int j = 1; j <= 30; j++) //Width
        {
            if (*height == i && *width == j){
                posArr[i][j] = "¤ ";
                //printf("¤ ");
            }
            else {
                posArr[i][j] = ". ";
                //printf(". ");
            }
        }
    }
}

void addBoard(){
    int h, w;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Width: ");
        scanf("%d", w);
        printf("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", h);

        buildBoard(&w,&h);

        //Add length later
        printBoard();
    }
}

int main() {
    printInstructions();
    int a=3, b=5;
    buildBoard(&a,&b);
    printBoard();
    clearBoard();
    //addBoard();
}
```

Comment: You incorrectly index arrays, from `1` to out of range, instead of from `0`. For example `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)` should be `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Comment: You are also passing `scanf` function `int` instead of `int*`.

Comment: This is an excellent opportunity to start using debugger. You can step through the code and observe variables as you go.

Comment: `scanf("%d", w); ... scanf("%d", h);` --> `scanf("%d", &w); ... scanf("%d", &h);`

Comment: Thanks! I realise the indexing problem, it was a failed atempt at making the code more readable and removing the issue of the user adding a component at 0,0 so that the array starts at 1,1 and is more user friendly. :)

Tried the "&" sign but it rendered nothing. Just get this and no more...

"[Running] cd "c:\Users\Juliet\Desktop\C-Cpp\" && gcc Sketchy.c -o Sketchy && "c:\Users\Juliet\Desktop\C-Cpp\"Sketchy"

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code **(Slightly modifying your code)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *posArr[10][30];

void printInstructions(){
    printf("Hello and welcome! Here you can configure your own breadboard\n");
    printf("To do this you will use coordinates using this syntax:\n");
    printf("width: 3\n");
    printf("height: 5\n");
    printf("After that a component will be choosen.\n");
    printf("It would look like below:\n");
}

void printBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            printf("%s", posArr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void clearBoard(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            posArr[i][j] = ". ";
        }
    }
}

void buildBoard(int *width, int *height){
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 30; j++)
        {
            if (*height == i && *width == j){
                posArr[i][j] = "¤ ";
            }
            else {
                posArr[i][j] = ". ";
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    printInstructions();
    int a=3, b=5;
    buildBoard(&a,&b);
    printBoard();
    clearBoard();
}
```

Comment: addBoard() function didn't  use in question code. So, i deleted that function. Without that function, it works well. You can run it in online compiler in this link "http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual"

Comment: You should explain what you did to correct the code